# Creating a list from json output

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-awx

Given the below output of `application_stop_time_output`, I want to create a list of dicts which contain only `item` and `stdout`. `stdout` should be an interger.

```yaml
- debug:
     msg: "{{ application_stop_time_output }}"
```

gives:

```
ok: [ebppdoxs10] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                "changed": true, 
                "cmd": "application_stop_time_format=$(echo \"[1/19/23 21:05:04:013 GMT+5:30] 0000 ApplicationMg A WSVR220I: Application stopped: ActivePackProdTest_war\"|awk '{print $1\" \"$2}'|cut -c 2-|rev | sed 's/:/ /' | rev| awk '{print $1\" \"$2}')\n\napplication_stop_time=$(date -d \"$application_stop_time_format\" +%s)\necho $application_stop_time\n", 
                "delta": "0:00:00.009048", 
                "end": "2023-01-20 23:26:19.995453", 
                "failed": false, 
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "application_stop_time_format=$(echo \"[1/19/23 21:05:04:013 GMT+5:30] 0000 ApplicationMg A WSVR220I: Application stopped: ActivePackProdTest_war\"|awk '{print $1\" \"$2}'|cut -c 2-|rev | sed 's/:/ /' | rev| awk '{print $1\" \"$2}')\n\napplication_stop_time=$(date -d \"$application_stop_time_format\" +%s)\necho $application_stop_time\n", 
                        "_uses_shell": true, 
                        "argv": null, 
                        "chdir": null, 
                        "creates": null, 
                        "executable": null, 
                        "removes": null, 
                        "stdin": null, 
                        "stdin_add_newline": true, 
                        "strip_empty_ends": true, 
                        "warn": true
                    }
                }, 
                "item": "[1/19/23 21:05:04:013 GMT+5:30] 0000 ApplicationMg A WSVR220I: Application stopped: ActivePackProdTest_war", 
                "rc": 0, 
                "start": "2023-01-20 23:26:19.986405", 
                "stderr": "", 
                "stderr_lines": [], 
                "stdout": "1674142504", 
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "1674142504"
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                "changed": true, 
                "cmd": "application_stop_time_format=$(echo \"[1/19/23 20:04:04:013 GMT+5:30] 0000 ApplicationMg A WSVR220I: Application stopped: ActivePackProdTest_war\"|awk '{print $1\" \"$2}'|cut -c 2-|rev | sed 's/:/ /' | rev| awk '{print $1\" \"$2}')\n\napplication_stop_time=$(date -d \"$application_stop_time_format\" +%s)\necho $application_stop_time\n", 
                "delta": "0:00:00.009918", 
                "end": "2023-01-20 23:26:23.887901", 
                "failed": false, 
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "application_stop_time_format=$(echo \"[1/19/23 20:04:04:013 GMT+5:30] 0000 ApplicationMg A WSVR220I: Application stopped: ActivePackProdTest_war\"|awk '{print $1\" \"$2}'|cut -c 2-|rev | sed 's/:/ /' | rev| awk '{print $1\" \"$2}')\n\napplication_stop_time=$(date -d \"$application_stop_time_format\" +%s)\necho $application_stop_time\n", 
                        "_uses_shell": true, 
                        "argv": null, 
                        "chdir": null, 
                        "creates": null, 
                        "executable": null, 
                        "removes": null, 
                        "stdin": null, 
                        "stdin_add_newline": true, 
                        "strip_empty_ends": true, 
                        "warn": true
                    }
                }, 
                "item": "[1/19/23 20:04:04:013 GMT+5:30] 0000 ApplicationMg A WSVR220I: Application stopped: ActivePackProdTest_war", 
                "rc": 0, 
                "start": "2023-01-20 23:26:23.877983", 
                "stderr": "", 
                "stderr_lines": [], 
                "stdout": "1674138844", 
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "1674138844"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
ok: [ebppdoxs10] => {
    "msg": {
          "results": [
            {
               "item": "[1/19/23 21:05:04:013 GMT+5:30] 0000 ApplicationMg A WSVR220I: Application stopped: ActivePackProdTest_war", 
               "stdout": 1674142504, 
            }, 
            {
              "item": "[1/19/23 20:04:04:013 GMT+5:30] 0000 ApplicationMg A WSVR220I: Application stopped: ActivePackProdTest_war", 
              "stdout": 1674138844, 
           }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to attempt fulfilling your above requirement and what isn't working as expected? See: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/keep_keys_filter.html as a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use loop for this and iterate to the results list together with loop_control and label [`loo_control-label`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label) to avoid each long item (iteration) be displayed.

Note that I have modified a bit the output but you can get the idea.

```js
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    results: [
              {
                  "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                  "changed": true, 
                  "cmd": "application_stop_time_format=$(echo \"[1/19/23 21:05:04:013 GMT+5:30] 0000 ApplicationMg A WSVR220I: Application stopped: ActivePackProdTest_war\"|awk '{print $1\" \"$2}'|cut -c 2-|rev | sed 's/:/ /' | rev| awk '{print $1\" \"$2}')\n\napplication_stop_time=$(date -d \"$application_stop_time_format\" +%s)\necho $application_stop_time\n", 
                  "delta": "0:00:00.009048", 
                  "end": "2023-01-20 23:26:19.995453", 
                  "failed": false, 
                  "invocation": {
                      "module_args": {
                          "_raw_params": "application_stop_time_format=$(echo \"[1/19/23 21:05:04:013 GMT+5:30] 0000 ApplicationMg A WSVR220I: Application stopped: ActivePackProdTest_war\"|awk '{print $1\" \"$2}'|cut -c 2-|rev | sed 's/:/ /' | rev| awk '{print $1\" \"$2}')\n\napplication_stop_time=$(date -d \"$application_stop_time_format\" +%s)\necho $application_stop_time\n", 
                          "_uses_shell": true, 
                          "argv": null, 
                          "chdir": null, 
                          "creates": null, 
                          "executable": null, 
                          "removes": null, 
                          "stdin": null, 
                          "stdin_add_newline": true, 
                          "strip_empty_ends": true, 
                          "warn": true
                      }
                  }, 
                  "item": "[1/19/23 21:05:04:013 GMT+5:30] 0000 ApplicationMg A WSVR220I: Application stopped: ActivePackProdTest_war", 
                  "rc": 0, 
                  "start": "2023-01-20 23:26:19.986405", 
                  "stderr": "", 
                  "stderr_lines": [], 
                  "stdout": "1674142504", 
                  "stdout_lines": [
                      "1674142504"
                  ]
              }, 
              {
                  "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                  "changed": true, 
                  "cmd": "application_stop_time_format=$(echo \"[1/19/23 20:04:04:013 GMT+5:30] 0000 ApplicationMg A WSVR220I: Application stopped: ActivePackProdTest_war\"|awk '{print $1\" \"$2}'|cut -c 2-|rev | sed 's/:/ /' | rev| awk '{print $1\" \"$2}')\n\napplication_stop_time=$(date -d \"$application_stop_time_format\" +%s)\necho $application_stop_time\n", 
                  "delta": "0:00:00.009918", 
                  "end": "2023-01-20 23:26:23.887901", 
                  "failed": false, 
                  "invocation": {
                      "module_args": {
                          "_raw_params": "application_stop_time_format=$(echo \"[1/19/23 20:04:04:013 GMT+5:30] 0000 ApplicationMg A WSVR220I: Application stopped: ActivePackProdTest_war\"|awk '{print $1\" \"$2}'|cut -c 2-|rev | sed 's/:/ /' | rev| awk '{print $1\" \"$2}')\n\napplication_stop_time=$(date -d \"$application_stop_time_format\" +%s)\necho $application_stop_time\n", 
                          "_uses_shell": true, 
                          "argv": null, 
                          "chdir": null, 
                          "creates": null, 
                          "executable": null, 
                          "removes": null, 
                          "stdin": null, 
                          "stdin_add_newline": true, 
                          "strip_empty_ends": true, 
                          "warn": true
                      }
                  }, 
                  "item": "[1/19/23 20:04:04:013 GMT+5:30] 0000 ApplicationMg A WSVR220I: Application stopped: ActivePackProdTest_war", 
                  "rc": 0, 
                  "start": "2023-01-20 23:26:23.877983", 
                  "stderr": "", 
                  "stderr_lines": [], 
                  "stdout": "1674138844", 
                  "stdout_lines": [
                      "1674138844"
                  ]
              }
          ]


  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: 
          - "{{ item.item }}"
          - "{{ item.stdout }}"
      loop: "{{ results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: item.item ## Here we use the item key as a label to limit the displayed output.
```

Gives:

```js
TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => (item=item.item) => {
    "msg": [
        "[1/19/23 21:05:04:013 GMT+5:30] 0000 ApplicationMg A WSVR220I: Application stopped: ActivePackProdTest_war",
        "1674142504"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=item.item) => {
    "msg": [
        "[1/19/23 20:04:04:013 GMT+5:30] 0000 ApplicationMg A WSVR220I: Application stopped: ActivePackProdTest_war",
        "1674138844"
    ]
}
```